# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.K9

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been uploading this app to Google Play a number of times without problem. I didn't change any of the build files (I'm using Eclipse) and it runs fine if I install it from the IDE. However, after my latest update to Google Play, when I tried installing it from there (I had to uninstall it first from the device; some sort of problem with different certificate signatures), it crashes immediately:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.K9: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.K9" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4588)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.K9" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
... 11 more
```

I checked out all the answers on Stack Overflow to the identical problem and none of them helped. I'm at my wits end about this and maybe the worst thing is, I can't even back out the update on Google Play because when I try, I get an error:

```
This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously matched version 4059 to version 4055, which would occur when 
API levels in range 13+ and 
Release track excluding all of [BETA] and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge].
```

Here's the relevant part of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid"
android:versionCode="4062"
android:versionName="4.33" >

<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="13"
   android:targetSdkVersion="20"
   />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<!-- Needed to mark a contact as contacted -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="org.thialfihar.android.apg.permission.READ_KEY_DETAILS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

<permission
    android:name="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT"
    android:description="@string/read_attachment_desc"
    android:label="@string/read_attachment_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT" />

<permission
    android:name="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.permission.REMOTE_CONTROL"
    android:description="@string/remote_control_desc"
    android:label="@string/remote_control_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.permission.REMOTE_CONTROL" />

<permission
    android:name="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.permission.READ_MESSAGES"
    android:description="@string/read_messages_desc"
    android:label="@string/read_messages_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.permission.READ_MESSAGES" />

<permission
    android:name="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.permission.DELETE_MESSAGES"
    android:description="@string/delete_messages_desc"
    android:label="@string/delete_messages_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.permission.DELETE_MESSAGES" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<!-- android:hardwareAccelerated attribute workaround for Android bug in WebView -->
<application
    android:name="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.K9"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
    android:allowTaskReparenting="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/chiaramail_icon_red"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.K9.Light" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value="com.chiaramail.chiaramailforandroid.activity.Search" />
```

The manifest hadn't changed either, except for android:versionCode, which I incremented before building. My devices are Samsung Galaxy S III and Galaxy Note 8.0, running Android 4.4.2 and 4.4.3, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason, the problem just went away. I have no idea how, but it's no longer happening and the app starts up just fine. Probably a weird unreproducible Eclipse bug; I hate it when that happens.

Comment: It's better to make a google about the possible consequences before updating or backing out any update.